# The button has no operation. How to use the switch as a function

Tags: javascript, if-statement, button, onclick, switch-statement

I just started learning javascript and this is my first problem.
I tried this method but it did not work. Please advise how I can use the switch as a function in events.
Thanks in advance for your guidance

```js
function lbl() {
      switch (new Date().getDate()) {
            case 0: {
                  document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = "sunday";
                  break;
            }
            case 1: {
                  document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = "monday";
                  break;
            }
            case 2: {
                  document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = "tuesday";
                  break;
            }
            case 3: {
                  document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = "wednesday";
                  break;
            }
            case 4: {
                  document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = "thursday";
                  break;
            }
            case 5: {
                  document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = "friday";
                  break;
            }
            case 6: {
                  document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = "saturday";
                  break;
            }
      }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width= auto, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
      <h1 id="show">show date! </h1>
      <button onclick=lbl()>click me!</button>
      <script src="js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **getDate()** method returns the day of the month (from 1 to 31).

The **getDay()** method returns the day of the week (from 0 to 6) for the specified date.

Just switch **getDate()** to **getDay()** and your code will work

Comment: thank you very much . Forgive me for my simple question. I have just started learning.My problem was solved

Comment: No problem, you are doing great! Keep it up! :)